# How to get data from subcollection into Stream

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My database is set up as follows:

[image]

I have a Stream set up to get a list of dates from the `dates` collection (far left).

```
  List<Date> _listOfDatesFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Date(
        doc.id,
        doc['title'],
        doc['description'],
        doc['approxLocation'],
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<Date>> get allDatesStream {
    return dateCollection.snapshots().map(_listOfDatesFromSnapshot);
  }
```

But as part of the Stream, I want to include data in the `reviews` collection of each date. This allows me to create a single list of Dates and sort by number of reviews, etc.

How can I get the data from a subcollection and use it in this Stream? I have considered having multiple Streams, but I need to know the id of the date, so I don't think it would work.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you are trying to use is in a subcollection, yes, you would need to use another Stream, you have access to de id here

```
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {

  //You should create the new stream here with a new function
  //that fetches the subcollection for every document.
  _listOfDataFromReviews(
    FirebeaseFirestore.instance.collection('firstCollection').doc(doc.id).collection('yourSubcollection').snapshots().  
  );

  return Date(
    doc.id,
    doc['title'],
    doc['description'],
    doc['approxLocation'],
  );
}).toList();
```

However you should think about if you really need a subcollection. Subcollections are used when the amount of documents can grow almost indefinitely. Perhaps instead of using a subcollection `reviews` can be a `Map` or a `List`. You can even add maps inside other maps and those are retrieved together with the document hence you can access them as any other variable, not to mention it will reduce the amount of reads you are using in firestore.

Here's an example if you were using reviews as a `List` of `Maps`

[image: List of Maps example]